# psql: FATAL: password authentication failed for user

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to connnect to Postgresql 9.1 database on remote ubuntu 12.04  server  from my windows pc using putty.i have created user with password and when i run the command

psql -U opentaps -d opentaps 
 (opentaps is the user i created for database opentaps)
i get the below mesaage .
psql: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "opentaps"
i did try psql -U opentaps  -d opentaps -h localhost 
but still same message after i supply the password .
my password for the opentaps user is correct .also even when i try 
psql -U postgres  -d postgres i get the same failure message .

I made some changes in pg_hba.conf and it looks like this

https://docs.google.com/document/d/13ymGYj9e7YPFiaffwixLzsWJygp_OfBmgBi4Axgrg5A/edit?usp=sharing

also in postgresql.conf i made the change by uncomenting
listen_addresses = '*'
i know i am missing something here .need your help to know what else i need to change to connect to the server.

thanks for your help

Comment: It doesn't look like a `pg_hba.conf` or `listen_addresses` problem. Assuming certainty that it's the correct password, I'd check its validity with `select usename,valuntil from pg_user`. If you can't connect at all, replace temporarily `md5` with `trust` in pg_hba.conf to bypass the password.

Comment: yes i did change the md5 with trust in pg_hba.conf  and restarted postgresql and voila this time it connected.thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8):

One hack around this is to edit pg_hba.conf

```
sudo vi /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf
```

To temporarily

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                   trust
```

Then go and

```
sudo -u postgres psql template1
ALTER USER postgres with encrypted password 'your_password';
```

then go back and set pg_hba.conf back to

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                   md5
```

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that you are logged in as the user `opentaps` when you launch `psql` from the command line.

you should also fill the `.pgpass` file with correct information, with the following format:

```
hostname:port:database:username:password
```

if no `.pgpass` file has been created, you should create one. cf. postgresql [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/libpq-pgpass.html) for reference

Comment: Since `-U opentaps` is explicitly passed, the logged in username is not relevant. And if the password entered by hand is rejected, it will be equally rejected from a .pgpass file.

Comment: Daniel you are correct .i did create this file .pgpass as per the docs but it didnt help i still got the same failure message.

Answer (score 1):

A little late response but here it goes:

First, your `.pgpass` file should be in your Ubuntu user's home directory. If there isn't a file you can create it with `nano ~/.pgpass`

Second, your file should contain this format `hostname:port:database:username:password`. Don't forget to `chmod 0600 ~/.pgpass` so you can disallow any access to world or group, as it says [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/libpq-pgpass.html).

Now, the command should be something like this: `psql -h localhost -w -U opentaps -d opentaps -c "select * from mytable"`. Where:

`-h` is your `host`.

`-w` is to use your .pgpass file, in case you don't want to type your password. Ohterwise use `-W` to force psql to prompt a password.

`-U` is your postgres username.

`-d` is your database name.

and `-c` is to execute a string sql command.

Comment: just says password authentication failed.