# PostgreSQL 9.4 REMOTE password Authentication Failed for 'postgres' user, however able to connect LOCALLY with SAME USER

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

**I am able to connect LOCALLY to the postgres user but NOT Remotely. This is a different issue then the one noted in [Auth Failed for Local Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19778510/psql-fatal-password-authentication-failed-for-user) **

I have PostgreSQL installed on a VM, and am able to connect remotely with one user called 'myapp', **but when I try to login remotely with the 'postgres' user I get** an:

Error connecting to the server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres" FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"

However when I attempt to **login** **locally** as postgres it **succeeds**:

`vagrant@postgresql:~$ psql -U postgres
Password for user postgres: 
psql (9.4.5)
Type "help" for help.
postgres=#`

Here are the full configurations for my pg_hba.conf file:

`local   all             postgres                                md5
local   all             all                                     md5
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5`

Also I added:
postgresql.conf: 
`listen_addresses = '*'`

Please help me understand what I am doing wrong, why is it that a random user can login from a remote connection but then I cannot log into postgres user remotely? The key here is that I want to be able to create a user that I can log in remotely. i'm seeing the same issue when creating 
`create role me with login password 'me';` , with that I cannot log in remotely either but locally I can.

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting to the same PostgreSQL instance in both cases?

Comment: there is only one postgres instance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [psql: FATAL: password authentication failed for user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19778510/psql-fatal-password-authentication-failed-for-user)

Comment: Christian your link is about a completely different issue. Your link describes an issue with local connections I do not have that problem!! My problem is with REMOTE connection when local clearly works fine.