# psql password authentication failed for user on mac with no "pg_hba.conf"

Tags: macos, postgresql, psql

i am really super frustrated/lost so I would appreciate any help I can get here. I have searched all over Google and SO and it seems nobody has had my problem yet.

Symptom: when i try to run `psql` in command line, or connect to any GUI postgresql client like Postgres or Postico, I get errors like `FATAL:  password authentication failed for user <myusername>`. It asks me for my username where it shouldn't ask for one.

All the advice online goes along the lines of "find your `pg_hba.conf` file and add these magic lines to it", but here's the thing: I don't have a `pg_hba.conf` file! The normal location (on a Mac) seems to be in `/etc/postgresql` (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19778510/psql-fatal-password-authentication-failed-for-user)) and this folder just plain doesnt exist on my mac even though I have installed all the other postgresql paraphernalia.

There's a remote possibility that [my pg_hba.conf is in some other location](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256534/how-do-i-find-the-path-to-pg-hba-conf-from-the-shell) but guess what! i need a running psql instance to find it! whoop-dee-heckin-do chicken and egg!

I notice these instructions are also like 3+ years out of date so there could be a change in the location or the filename and I have no idea what to find. Please help! I just want to connect to my sql database in localhost to learn web development.

thanks very much.

Comment: This shows how to find pg_hba.conf (it definitely exists) on a mac:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025972/postgresql-how-to-find-pg-hba-conf-file-using-mac-os-x